# Binding Swift properties to NSTableView?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nstableview

I think I have programmed myself into a corner, but I'm hoping you all know a way out. I have a class...

```
class Card {
    var order: Int? = -1
    var tag: String = "0"
    var comment: String?
    var data : [String: NSNumber]
}
```

Ideally everything would be in `data`, which is a few strings and lots of numbers. I started with `[String, String]` but I found I was writing lots of code to cast and convert when I wanted to (say) compare one of those numbers to zero. Changing it to `[String, NSNumber]` simplified all *that* code, but now my tableViewDataSource becomes very complex because some of the data is in `data` and some is in a separate property like `comment`. I even tried `[String, Any]`, but then everything had to be cast all the time to do anything.

I have a feeling I am missing something fundamental here. When working with NSTableViews, is there a simple way to use Swift properties that I'm missing? valueForKey: does not work, there's no easy way to do a reflection-like solution I know of, etc. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can only bind `dynamic` properties, and your class needs to inherit from `NSObject` or implement `NSObjectProtocol`. Additionally, nilable value-types aren't allowed, so you cannot bind `Int?`

ie.:

```
class Card: NSObject {
    dynamic var order: Int = -1
    dynamic var tag: String = "0"
    dynamic var comment: String?
    dynamic var data: [String: NSNumber]
}
```

Comment: So am I correct in understanding that using NSObject and dynamic makes valueForKey work? If so that is an excellent solution, and one that I should have stumbled across before now.